# Multiple Traits on one model from chelout/laravel-relationship-events

Tags: laravel, polymorphic-associations, laravel-7, laravel-events

I am building a model and using chelout/laravel-relationship-events to capture events.

I have a model that looks like this:

```
    class Taxonomyterm extends Model
    {
    use HasMorphToManyEvents, HasMorphedByManyEvents {
        HasMorphedByManyEvents::newMorphToMany insteadof HasMorphToManyEvents;
    }
    ...
    public function images()
    {
        return $this->morphToMany(Image::class, 'imageable')->withTimestamps();
    }

    public function items()
    {
        return $this->morphedByMany(Item::class, 'taxonomytermable')->orderBy('taxonomytermables.id')->withPivot('id')->withTimestamps();
    }
    ...    
    protected static function boot()
    {
        parent::boot();
        static::morphToManyAttached(function ($relation, $parent, $ids, $attributes) {
            if( $relation == 'images') {
                dd('Attached MorphToMany');
            }
        }

        static::morphedByManyAttached(function ($relation, $parent, $ids, $attributes) {
            if( $relation == 'items') {
                dd('Attached MorphedByMany');
            }
        }
    }
```

I was pointed to PHP [docs](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.traits.php#language.oop5.traits.conflict) by the maintainer of the package, and can't seem to find the right way to make this work.

I also assume that newMorphToMany is the method that conflicts between the two traits.

I am essentially lost on what to do from here to get both HasMorphToManyEvents and HasMorphedByManyEvents working on the same model.
[Package this is from](https://github.com/chelout/laravel-relationship-events)

Comment: Try like this, and if work i will give you more info..
`use HasMorphToManyEvents, HasMorphedByManyEvents {
        HasMorphedByManyEvents::newMorphToMany as public HasMorphToManyEvents;
    }`

Comment: That gives me: Trait method newMorphToMany has not been applied, because there are collisions with other trait methods on App\\Taxonomyterm

Comment: Actually, I don't see any error on your code. What's the execution error with your current code ?

Comment: Any error message ? Any github repo to try it locally ?

Comment: HasMorphedByMany and HasMorphToMany both use the newMorphToMany method and conflict with each other, so you can't use both on one model.

Answer (score 0):

You need to be sure of the conflicting method among the two traits. Assuming that `newMorphToMany` is the conflicting method:

You need to rename one of them as follows if you need them both available.

```
class Taxonomyterm extends Model
{
    use HasMorphToManyEvents, HasMorphedByManyEvents {
        HasMorphedByManyEvents::newMorphToMany insteadof HasMorphToManyEvents;
        HasMorphToManyEvents::newMorphToMany as newMorphToMany2;
    }
    // ... more code
}
```

Now, wherever you need to use `HasMorphToManyEvents::newMorphToMany` within the `Taxonomyterm class` you call it using it's new name, `newMorphToMany2`. Otherwise, `newMorphToMany` will always refer to `HasMorphedByManyEvents::newMorphToMany` within this class.
Just to emphasize, you need to find out and be sure of the conflicting method in the two traits. I hope this leads you towards a solution...

Comment: How do you get the events to use newMorphToMany2?